# WebExtensions: is it possible to intercept/register a handler with the "file open" dialogs?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a Web Extension that occasionally deals in files -- usually by sending off a URL to the file to a remote server or by downloading the file at the user's request and shipping off the bytes to the same server.

This works fine for most use-cases, but sometimes you'll come across a site that automatically triggers a download of a file and pops open the file-open dialog for the user to handle. I wasn't able to find any documentation or filed bugs to this effect, but is there a way to register an extension to appear as a handler in that dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Its currently not possible to add an icon to the file chooser dialog with WebExtensions. Feel free to open a feature request here: http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

If you want to handle an action whenever a download occurs, you can use
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/onCreated